# how to get pdf file from .acsm file of google book api in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, google-api-java-client, google-books

I am trying to download free ebook pdf file through google book api, but I don't succeed. When I check in browser what output comes then that link is giving me download of .acsm format file in explorer or browser. So how I can I download pdf file from .acsm link OR Convert .acsm to pdf format.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** To download free books .pdf format from Google Book API, we need to get the download link of pdf from JSON query and then send it into webview. That's it.

```
String url = "http://books.google.co.in/books/download/The_Child_s_Own_Story_Book.pdf?id=9WevWtW5KMUC&hl=&output=pdf&sig=ACfU3U0LWT7WWnfdtxAFbBctZk4aALv8gA&source=gbs_api";

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: are you able to load pdf from above url in WebView?